# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character:

Tags: database, h2

When I am trying to insert data to H2 table, it is showing the below exception.

> INSERT INTO DATA (IP,HEADERS,METHOD,BODY,ID,TIME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) -- (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6) [90004-175]
>
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "[accept=application/json, activityid=caf59f7d-b2f1-4250-9e7a-61606ff5dace, Authorization=Bearer dc98a786-6dda-35e0-9086-7a3beba5edd5, Content-Length=19, Content-Type=application/json, Host=190.0.0.101:8248, User-Agent=curl/7.58.0]"; SQL statement:
>   INSERT INTO DATA (IP,HEADERS,METHOD,BODY,ID,TIME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) -- (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6) [90004-175]
>
> Table :
>   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA (
>       TIME BIGINT,
>       ID VARCHAR(255),
>       METHOD VARCHAR(255),
>       HEADERS BLOB,
>       BODY BLOB,
>       IP VARCHAR(255),
>       PRIMARY KEY(ID)
>   );

What can be the reason for this? How can I resolve it? Is this a problem of that type or value of inserting.

Appreciate your valuable input here.

Comment: Is there any update for this problem?

Comment: I got this due to BLOB type columns. once I use the RAWTOHEX() function, it resolved. RAWTOHEX('[accept=application/json, activityid=84030318-7095-46ad-aea1-50d8644fef3f]'),RAWTOHEX('world'),'10.100.5.22'); Didn't check the RCA further.

Comment: In my case it was because of nativeQuery, JPQL can automatically translate enum to string, in other case I had to parse enum to string